# Why does Hoshi wear a Blue (science division) uniform when she is the comms officer?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In TOS, Uhura was the comms officer, and wore the red of the operations division. In enterprise, the colors seem to be the same as TOS. Archer (captain) and Travis (helmsman) wore gold, the medical staff wore blue, and the engineers, security and tactical wore red. So why would Hoshi not wear red?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hoshi_Sato) Hoshi was a linguist and not an operation officer.

She is a scientist stationed on the ship just like a doctor, meaning she gets a blue uniform.

Comment: What did I miss? All their uniforms were the same color.

Comment: there was a division colour stripe on the uniforms

Comment: @JohnSaunders there were two stripes defining division  on each uniform.

Answer (score 23):

While Hoshi was the comm officer, she was primarily a translator. Just as Spock was first officer, but was department head of sciences. Since there was more first contact occurring on the mission of NX-01, and the Universal Translator was not as well developed, Hoshi was doing original research. So while a comms officer would normally be someone from the operations division, it wasn't always the case.